# AJAX addToCart not working for every visitor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**UPDATE:
It was cause by jQuery library, which wasn't working properly only in IE9. It was jQuery 2.x. I am not sure what was exactly the problem, but switching to jQuery 1.x solved the problem ;).**

I just deployed new e-shop with AJAX functionality, which add product to cart via AJAX. But some visitors have trouble with adding product to cart. They have JavaScript=on, but AJAX function for adding product to cart is not working... Where possibly could be problem?

For a majority of visitors this function work perfectly. I run out of ideas, why it's not working for everybody (I tested this function on IE7 (XP), IE8(Win7) and newer (Win7+8) and it works perfectly).

Here is the function:

```
function addToCart()
    {
        var product = getCurrentProduct();

        $.post("action/cart.php", {
            action: "add",
            product_id: product.product_id,
            product_variant_id: product.variant_id,
            count: $('#product-quantity').val()
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.ok) {
        //THIS is only fancy stuff
                $('#product-added-box').slideDown();
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#product-added-box').slideUp();
                }, 5000);
            }
            updateCartCount();
        }, "json")
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty vague, it is hard to pinpoint the issue. If it works for most people it seems unlikely it would be a PHP error and if it is a Javascript issue you should be getting some sort of error. I can't deduce much else without all of the code involved.

Comment: You're going to have to instrument on both client and server and attempt to capture info about a case that fails so you can see what might be happening.  There is no other way to go.  For example, are you ever getting any malformed requests on your server?   For the user's that fail, what happens with their ajax call?  Does it fail to go through?  Does it get an error back from the server?  You need some logging there so you can find out what is happening there.  You could even capture client error info from the post and send it back to your server on a separate ajax call.

Comment: You might also check to make sure you don't have any concurrency issues on your server (multiple requests arriving in close proximity).

Comment: I am creating debug page for visitors, it can test javascript support and support of AJAX (sending some ajax request) and then showing log to textarea, and then visitor send me text from textarea via e-mail. And there is also console log written to this textarea. Is this page usefull for solving my issue?

Answer (score 0):

The poster has already solved the problem, but I'm adding this for the benefit of future users. The problem was that OP was using jQuery 2.x; switching to jQuery 1.x solved the problem.

Here's the reason: jQuery 2.x doesn't support older versions of Internet Explorer. According to [**the jQuery website**](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x):

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but *does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8*. All the notes in the [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) apply here as well. Since IE 8 is still relatively common, we recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8 users are visiting the site. Please read the [2.0 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) carefully.

This lack of support is the reason your site was breaking in older versions of IE.

Comment: Well, I had two version of jQuery, before solving this problem. For older IE 6,7,8 I used jQuery 1.x and for other browsers jQuery 2.x (including IE 9, 10, 11). There is no info on jQuery website, why version 2.x is not compatible with IE9, and that was the problem.

Comment: Hmmm. That is odd. Which part of your `addToCart()` function was breaking? Have you tried testing it in IE9, but breaking it into pieces?

Comment: Maybe there was some other problem, but loading jQuery 2.x under IE 9 broke everything build on jQuery on that site. I just edited ifIE and I was not trying to find where exactly is bug, because it was already on live site.

Comment: I don't see any obvious culprits in the code you posted. If you also posted the source for `getCurrentProduct` and `updateCartCount`, we could also look for problems in those.

Comment: here is the link to live version of website: [link](http://www.jhdecor.cz). You can have a look at whole source code. In a header, there is this conditional: <!--[if lte IE 9]> and in it, is script for loading jQuery 1.9 instead of 2.1, which is used for non IE 5-9

Comment: I wasn't able to find the functions in question. Can you post the source for those functions?